# Fit an image completely in a box

Tags: html, css, image

Here I'm trying to add an image so it fits completely into a `div#image-container`. I'm using CSS styles:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

which helps to fit the width correctly into the div, but not the height. How do I fix this?.

I've added the snippet below:

```css
#image-container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 350px;
  border: 13px solid gold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #000;
  /*position: relative;*/
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aixcp.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
</div>
```

Comment: `background-size:100% 100%;` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif tnx that is solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size: 100% 100%;` solved the problem

```css
#image-container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 350px;
  border: 13px solid gold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #000;
  /*position: relative;*/
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aixcp.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
</div>
```